# Subtracting from a date the number of days in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime, stored-procedures

I would like to subtract number of days from a date with the format (`YY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`). Is there any automated function to perform this or would it be exhaustive coding to perform this task. I'm writing a stored procedure which encompasses the above task.

To be more clear lets say this is the date `2011-12-07 06:05:19.200` and I want to subtract 19 days from it and the result will be `2011-11-18 06:05:19.200` and the number of days is going to be a parameter in the SP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You deleted your identical question where I answered before, but here's a function that does what you need;

```
CREATE FUNCTION SUBTRACT_DAYS( @date AS DATETIME, @days AS INT )
RETURNS DATETIME
BEGIN
  RETURN DATEADD(dd, -@days, @date);
END;

SELECT dbo.SUBTRACT_DAYS('2011-12-07 06:05:19.200', 19);

> 2011-11-18 06:05:19.200
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DoSomethingUseful  @InputDate DATETIME, @NumberOfDays INT
AS BEGIN

   SELECT DATEADD(Day, @NumberOfDays, @InputDate)

END
```

and then call it like this:

```
EXEC dbo.DoSomethingUseful @InputDate = '2011-12-07T06:05:19.200', @NumberOfDays = -19
```

returns:

```
2011-11-18 06:05:19.200
```